# Listview with two types of highlightning

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, highlight

I'm using C# wpf and I have a listview where I want to set, say a dark highlight, when an item in the listview is double-clicked and if an item is single-clicked it should have a bright highlight. A double-clicked item should stay highlighted in dark until another item is double-clicked. How can I do this?

Comment: I can see that you've posted the same in http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/2f981cc0-e741-42a4-b6f6-8f75ed915c34. Is it working or are you expecting something else from here?

Comment: I'm wondering if there's a better way to do it than the solution posted in that thread.